# Match two character strings by location in R

Tags: r

```
string <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("A", append(rep(" ", 8), append("B", append(rep(" ", 17), "C"))))), collapse = "")
text <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("I love", append(rep(" ", 3), append("chocolate", append(rep(" ", 9), "pudding"))))), collapse = "")

string
[1] "       A        B                 C"
text
[1] "       I love   chocolate         pudding"
```

I am trying to match letters in "string" with text in "text" such that to the letter A corresponds the text "I love" to B corresponds "chocolate" and to C "pudding". Ideally, I would like to put A, B, C in column 1 and three different rows of a dataframe (or tibble) and the text in column 2 and the corresponding rows. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are all your `text`s 4 words long or does that vary?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know whether the strings in which you are trying to manipulate and then collate into columns in a `data.frame` follow a pattern. But for the example you posted, I suggest creating a list with the strings (`strings`):

```
strings <- list(string, text)
```

Then use `lapply()` which will in turn create a list for each element in `strings`.

```
res <-lapply(strings, function(x){
  grep(x=trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s\\s"))), pattern="[[:alpha:]]", value=TRUE)
})
```

In the code above, `strsplit()` splits the string whenever two spaces are found (`\\s\\s`). But the resulting split is a list with the strings as inner elements. Therefore you need to use `unlist()` so you can use it with `grep()`. `grep()` will select only those strings with an alphanumeric character --which is what you want.

You can then use `do.call(cbind, list)` to bind the elements in the resulting `lapply()` list into columns. The dimension must match for this work.

```
do.call(cbind, res)
```

Result:

```
> do.call(cbind, res)
     [,1] [,2]       
[1,] "A"  "I love"   
[2,] "B"  "chocolate"
[3,] "C"  "pudding"
```

You can wrap it up into a `as.data.frame()` for instance to get the desired result:

```
> as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, res), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  V1        V2
1  A    I love
2  B chocolate
3  C   pudding
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read.fwf` and get the positions using `nchar`.

```
read.fwf(file=textConnection(text),
 widths=c(diff(c(1, gregexpr("\\w", string)[[1]])), nchar(text)))[-1]
#         V2                 V3      V4
#1 I love    chocolate          pudding
```

In case the white spaces should be removed use also `trimws`:

```
trimws(read.fwf(file=textConnection(text),
 widths=c(diff(c(1, gregexpr("\\w", string)[[1]])), nchar(text)))[-1])
#[1] "I love"    "chocolate" "pudding"
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for situations in which C and "pudding" don't have the same initial character position? (e.g., C is in position 23, and pudding starts at 20, leaving C matched with "ding" and B with "chocolate pud")

Comment: Maybe ask a new questions for this situations, as the given solution will not easy be able to adapted to this new situation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, I came up with this workaround by using the package **stringr**. This only works with that kind of pattern, so in case you have erratic ones you need to adjust it.

The output is a `data.frame` with two columns given by your two input data and rows according to the matches.

```r
library(stringr)

string <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("A", append(rep(" ", 8), append("B", append(rep(" ", 17), "C"))))), collapse = "")
text <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("I love", append(rep(" ", 3), append("chocolate", append(rep(" ", 9), "pudding"))))), collapse = "")

string_nospace <- str_replace_all( string, "\\s{1,20}", " " )
string_nospace <- str_trim( string_nospace )
string_nospace <- data.frame( string = t(str_split(string_nospace, "\\s", simplify = TRUE)))

text_nospace <- str_replace_all( text, "\\s{2,20}", "_" )
text_nospace <- str_sub(text_nospace, start = 2)
text_nospace <- data.frame(text = t(str_split(text_nospace, "_", simplify = TRUE)))

df = data.frame(string = string_nospace, 
                text = text_nospace )
df
#>   string      text
#> 1      A    I love
#> 2      B chocolate
#> 3      C   pudding
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>