# Match characters with different starting points by location in R

Tags: r

```
string <- " A      B            C   "
text   <- " I love chocolate pudding"
```

I want to match each word in *text* with the respective letters in *string*. This question builds from a previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263591/match-two-character-strings-by-location-in-r) but adds the problem of matching text and letters in which the starting point between the two is not the same. For example, in this example, C in *string* starts at position:

```
gregexpr("\\S+", string[1])[[1]][3]
[1] 22
```

while the corresponding word "pudding" in *text* starts at position:

```
gregexpr("\\S+", text[1])[[1]][4]
[1] 19
```

This means that C (V4 in the example below) is linked with "ding":

```
read.fwf(file = textConnection(text), widths = c(diff(c(1, gregexpr("\\w+", string)[[1]])), nchar(text))) %>%
select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
       V2            V3   V4
1 I love  chocolate pud ding
```

while B (V3) with "chocolate pud" (and A, V2, with "I love").

Instead, I would like to match C with the whole word "pudding". In other words, the problem is to find a whole word in *text* based on a character position in *string*, even if the two (C and "pudding") don't start at the same position.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263727/9494044) answer to your previous question?

Comment: I tried the answer you refer to, yes, but it doesn't work because I'm searching for something that modifies "text" based on "string" (while that answer cbind the two strings based on a pattern, which I don't have in my actual analyses nor in my example here).

Comment: What is your expected output for this?

Comment: A data frame with letters in the first column, and the corresponding words in the second column.

A: I love
B: chocolate
C: pudding
D: NA

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do anyway? I think you'll get better answers if you could introduce us to the actual problem--albeit in an anonymized and generalized manner--you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is the actual problem I'm trying to solve. In my analyses I want to make it scalable and run it across multiple texts, but I already know how to do it. The problem is, as stated above, how to match two characters by their position (considering that their starting position is not the same). What I have in mind is (1) recognize the position of C (I know how to do that), and (2) identify in "text" a whole word that is contained in the position of C (the problem).

Comment: There is always one space between words (I, love) in *text* and it is variable between words (A, B) in *string*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think you could use a function that strips the strings of the spaces and makes all the letters and words elements of a vector. The match is then quite automatic. I hope this helps.

```
# Your example (different starting points)
string <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("A", append(rep(" ", 8), append("B", append(rep(" ", 20), append("C", append(rep(" ", 6), "D"))))))), collapse = "")
text <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("I love", append(rep(" ", 3), append("chocolate", append(rep(" ", 9), "pudding"))))), collapse = "")

# Function to get rid of spaces
strip_it <- function(x){
  ch_vector <- strsplit(x, "\\s")[[1]]
  indx      <- sapply(ch_vector, nchar)
  return(ch_vector[indx != 0])
}

# Use it on one vector
strip_it(string)

# Use it on all vectors containing letters and words that you want to match
sapply(list(string, text), strip_it)

# Other Example
v1 <- paste0(c(rep(" ", 4), "A", rep(" ", 4), "B", rep(" ", 4), "C", rep(" ", 4), "D"), collapse ="")
v2 <- paste0(c(rep(" ", 2), "InstructionalVideo", rep(" ", 2), "Mario?", rep(" ", 2), "Marioooo?", rep(" ", 2), "Mario?!?"), collapse ="")

sapply(list(v1, v2), strip_it)
```

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't work when the number of elements in the two vectors is not the same though..

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. In order to get the whole word, given a character position, we first need a function that gives 1 to the first position of all the words in text, and 0 to the rest (thanks to @Zoned for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287330/9845702) idea).

```
# Function 1,0
strip_it <- function(x){
  ch_vector <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  ch_vector[c(grep("\\s", ch_vector)) ] <- ""
  indx      <- sapply(ch_vector, nchar)
  return(indx)
}
```

Subsequently, we need to find the minimum distance between the character position and the starting position of the closest word.

```
# Function to find the min
findMin <- function(string, text, k){

  # find closest value to string position
  chs_note <- str_split(gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", string, perl=TRUE), " ")[[1]]
  pos_chr <- which(strsplit(string, " ")[[1]] == chs_note[k])
  pos_txt <- append(0, diff(strip_it(text)))
  pos_txt[pos_txt == -1] <- 0
  pos_min <- which(pos_txt == 1)
  minim <- which.min(abs(pos_min - pos_chr))

  # find whole word that starts at minim
  pos_txt2 <- strip_it(text)
  ch_vector <- strsplit(text, "")[[1]]
  ch_vector[c(grep("\\s", ch_vector)) ] <- ""
  indx      <- as.data.frame(cbind(V1 = ch_vector, 
                                   V2 =sapply(ch_vector, nchar)))
  rownames(indx) <- NULL
  rownames(indx) <- as.numeric(rownames(indx))

  complete <-  paste(as.character(indx[pos_min[minim]:
                               ifelse(length(chs_note) > k,
                                      which(strsplit(string, " ")[[1]] == chs_note[k+1]),
                                      nrow(indx))
                               , 1]), collapse = "-")
  complete1 <- gsub("\\-\\-", " ", complete)

  return(

    gsub("\\-", "", complete1, perl=TRUE)

  )
}
```

With the example:

```
string <- " A      B            C   "
text   <- " I love chocolate pudding"

findMin(string, text, 3)
[1] "pudding"
```